# AssertionFailedException on ViewerComparator constructor

Tags: java, swt, jface, tableviewer

I am trying to implement sorter for my TableViewer, which allows me to sort columns when I click header. However, I get this error when I try to construct my ViewerComparator :

```html
Exception in thread "main" org.eclipse.core.runtime.AssertionFailedException: null argument:
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.Assert.isNotNull(Assert.java:85)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.Assert.isNotNull(Assert.java:73)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.disassociate(StructuredViewer.java:640)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTableViewer.internalRefreshAll(AbstractTableViewer.java:735)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTableViewer.internalRefresh(AbstractTableViewer.java:649)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTableViewer.internalRefresh(AbstractTableViewer.java:636)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer$7.run(StructuredViewer.java:1457)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.preservingSelection(StructuredViewer.java:1392)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.preservingSelection(StructuredViewer.java:1353)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.refresh(StructuredViewer.java:1455)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.ColumnViewer.refresh(ColumnViewer.java:537)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.refresh(StructuredViewer.java:1414)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.setComparator(StructuredViewer.java:1752)
    at gui.EMI.portfolioTab(EMI.java:283)
    at gui.EMI.open(EMI.java:112)
    at gui.EMI.main(EMI.java:58)
```

Here is the code :

```html
import org.eclipse.core.runtime.Assert;
import org.eclipse.jface.viewers.ILabelProvider;
import org.eclipse.jface.viewers.TableViewer;
import org.eclipse.jface.viewers.Viewer;
import org.eclipse.jface.viewers.ViewerComparator;
import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.SelectionAdapter;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.SelectionEvent;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.SelectionListener;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Table;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TableColumn;

public class TableColumnSorter extends ViewerComparator {
    public static final int ASC = 1;
    public static final int NONE = 0;
    public static final int DESC = -1;

    private int direction = 0;
    private TableColumn column = null;
    private int columnIndex = 0;
    final private TableViewer viewer;

    final private SelectionListener selectionHandler = new SelectionAdapter() {
        public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
            TableColumnSorter sorter = (TableColumnSorter) TableColumnSorter.this.viewer.getComparator();
            Assert.isTrue(TableColumnSorter.this == sorter);
            TableColumn selectedColumn = (TableColumn) e.widget;
            Assert.isTrue(TableColumnSorter.this.viewer.getTable() == selectedColumn.getParent());
            TableColumnSorter.this.setColumn(selectedColumn);
        }
    };

  // HERE IS THE PART I GET ERROR

    public TableColumnSorter(TableViewer viewer) {
        this.viewer = viewer;
        Assert.isTrue(this.viewer.getComparator() == null);
        viewer.setComparator(this);

        for (TableColumn tableColumn : viewer.getTable().getColumns()) {
            tableColumn.addSelectionListener(selectionHandler);
        }
    }

    public void setColumn(TableColumn selectedColumn) {
        if (column == selectedColumn) {
            switch (direction) {
            case ASC:
                direction = DESC;
                break;
            case DESC:
                direction = ASC;
                break;
            default:
                direction = ASC;
                break;
            }
        } else {
            this.column = selectedColumn;
            this.direction = ASC;
        }

        Table table = viewer.getTable();
        switch (direction) {
        case ASC:
            table.setSortColumn(selectedColumn);
            table.setSortDirection(SWT.UP);
            break;
        case DESC:
            table.setSortColumn(selectedColumn);
            table.setSortDirection(SWT.DOWN);
            break;
        default:
            table.setSortColumn(null);
            table.setSortDirection(SWT.NONE);
            break;
        }

        TableColumn[] columns = table.getColumns();
        for (int i = 0; i < columns.length; i++) {
            TableColumn theColumn = columns[i];
            if (theColumn == this.column) columnIndex = i;
        }
        viewer.setComparator(null);
        viewer.setComparator(this);
    }

    @Override
    public int compare(Viewer viewer, Object e1, Object e2) {
        return direction * doCompare(viewer, e1, e2);
    }

    protected int doCompare(Viewer v, Object e1, Object e2) {
       Assert.isTrue(viewer == this.viewer);
       ILabelProvider labelProvider = (ILabelProvider) viewer.getLabelProvider(columnIndex);
        String t1 = labelProvider.getText(e1);
        String t2 = labelProvider.getText(e2);
        if (t1 == null) t1 = "";
        if (t2 == null) t2 = "";
        return t1.compareTo(t2);
    }
}
```

I called the method in below ways, same error :

```html
aTableViewer.setComparator(new TableColumnSorter(aTableViewer));

or

TableColumnSorter sorter = new TableColumnSorter(aTableViewer);
```

What might be the problem here, and why is implementing a sorter to TableViewer is that hard? I literally spent hours on this and still got nothing. Seems like good old WindowsFormsApp is more powerful than SWT/JFace.

Comment: The stack trace appears to be more to do with the items (TableItem) in the table rather than the comparator. The items appear to have been damaged - are you doing anything with the items in the contents provider or elsewhere?

Comment: I populate the Table with ResultSet came from database in the below code, and that's all. I won't write the whole code but here is the part I create TableItem, rest is just assigning texts to TableItems :

item = new TableItem(portfolioTable.getTable(), SWT.NONE);

Comment: You must use a Content Provider with TableViewer, creating TableItems directly is not supported.  Your assertion is because the items are not set up as expected by the viewer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you are getting is from the `refresh` that `setComparator` does. it is not actually caused by the comparator code.

You must use a Content Provider for the table contents when using TableViewer.

Creating TableItems directly is not supported.

Your assertion is because the items are not set up as expected by the viewer, using a content provider will do this properly.